# Draw user defined color rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle on the click of a button.
User can select a color and then click button to draw a specific colored rectangle.
How to get this property.
In my fiddle when you click Layer button you can get a rectangle on the canvas. if you uncheck the check box and click it again you will get a rectangle at the same place . I want to create different colored rectangles every time.
This is the code pen which describes the same colored rectangle every time.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ffhjg/

This is the code I am trying to edit.
It is drawing it with black every time now. :(

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zaFfw

Comment: to get faster help you should isolate the code you think is giving the problem, if you don't do that people could think you want them to do your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in your init3

```
var oMaterialCB = document.getElementById("pickColor");
        var sMaterial = oMaterialCB.options[oMaterialCB.selectedIndex].text;
        var sMaterialColor = oMaterialCB.options[oMaterialCB.selectedIndex].value;
        m_iCurrentLayerIndex = AddToCB('LayerList', sMaterial + 'Layer');


       //x,y, width, height
        var l_dYOfPrevLayer =  document.getElementById('TextLayer_ULy').value; 

        var Display_DY = DisplayCoords(l_dYOfPrevLayer);  //m_oSetup.Layers[m_iCurrentLayerIndex-1].BottomBoundary; 

        addRect(0,Display_DY,640,100, sMaterialColor);
        // get the last box, update the index for that box and type of that box


      }
```